# Using a variable in a match with Stash

Tags: stash

I'm trying to use a variable in a match for a stash get_list like so, but it doesn't appear to be working;

I'm setting an initial entry_id here for a place;

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="places"
    status="open"
    {global:channel_disable_basic}
}
{exp:stash:set name="place_id"}{entry_id}{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then I'm getting a list of events like so which contains an Event Venue as a custom field;

```
{exp:stash:set_list
    name="venue-events"
    parse_tags="yes"
    parse_conditionals="yes"
    parse_depth="3"
    save="yes"
    scope="site"
}
    {exp:calendar:cal
        calendar_id="4871"
        first_day_of_week="1"
        enable="custom_fields"
        date_range_start="today"
        date_range_end="+ 12 months"
        pad_short_weeks="n"
        dynamic="yes"
    }
        {stash:venue_event_title}{title}{/stash:venue_event_title}
        {stash:venue_event_venue}{cf_event_venue}{entry_id}{/cf_event_venue}{/stash:venue_event_venue}
    {/exp:calendar:cal}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Then finally i'm using the 'place' entry_id above to match against the 'venue_event_venue';

```
{exp:stash:get_list
    name="venue-events"
    require_prefix="no"
    parse_tags="yes"
    parse_depth="3"
    match="#^{exp:stash:get name='place_id'}$#"
    against="venue_event_venue"
}
    <pre>{venue_event_title}, {venue_event_date}, {venue_event_venue}</pre>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

I can't get `{exp:stash:get name='place_id'}` to work in the 'match' but on it's own it does return a value.

Grateful for any advice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit late, but anyhow: you need to use parse="inward" when passing a tag as a parameter:

```
{exp:stash:get_list
    name="venue-events"
    require_prefix="no"
    parse_tags="yes"
    parse_depth="3"
    match="#^{exp:stash:get name='place_id'}$#"
    against="venue_event_venue"
    parse="inward"
}
...
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Alternatively you can use the variable as a placeholder when wrapping with {exp:stash:parse}

```
{exp:stash:parse}
   {exp:stash:get_list
       name="venue-events"
       require_prefix="no"
       parse_tags="yes"
       parse_depth="3"
       match="#^{stash:place_id}$#"
       against="venue_event_venue"
       parse="inward"
   }
   ...
   {/exp:stash:get_list}

{exp:stash:parse}
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This code is untested!!

Depending on your exact template scenario, try this first:

```
//Set your stash to wrap the channel entry instead of being contained within
//Use trim to remove whitespace
{exp:stash:set name="place_id" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes"}
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="places"
    status="open"
    {global:channel_disable_basic}
}
{entry_id}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

If that doesnt work, set the stash as a snippet:

```
{exp:stash:set name="place_id" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes" type="snippet"}
…
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Then get it using traditional snippet style:

```
{exp:stash:get_list
    name="venue-events"
    require_prefix="no"
    parse_tags="yes"
    parse_depth="3"
    match="#^{place_id}$#"
    against="venue_event_venue"
}
```

I guess if all that fails you can try `{exp:stash:parse}` something like this:

```
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
{exp:stash:get_list
    name="venue-events"
    match="#^{exp:stash:get name='place_id'}$#"
    against="venue_event_venue"
}
    <pre>{venue_event_title}, {venue_event_date}, {venue_event_venue}</pre>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Comment: Yeah, sadly nothing gets rendered. :(